# Perform database query in Django channels

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm trying to create a very simple system where an user, in order to use a consumer, needs to input a key in the WS url, like : `ws://127.0.0.1:8000/main?key=KEY`. Once the consumer is called, Django Channels needs to perform a very simple DB query to check if the key exists:

```
class TestConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        ...
        key_query = await database_sync_to_async(keys.objects.get(key=key))
        ...
```

But the problem with this code is that it will give the following error:

```
You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`database_sync_to_async` must be called on the method, not on the result of the method:

```
key_query = await database_sync_to_async(keys.objects.get)(key=key)
```

Comment: Best is to wrape your whole database access in a separate method. See https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/databases.html#database-sync-to-async