# Django: Query database from Channels consumers

Tags: django, django-channels

I had a Django app that had live chat working. Now I am trying to add a query to the database within the `connect` method. I am following the Channels documentation, and tried the solution in [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64915085/perform-database-query-in-django-channels) but nothing is working.

Below is my code. The error I'm seeing in the Javascript console is `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9008/ws/chat/334/' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. I do have redis-server running on localhost and that was working before, so that's not a problem.

```
async def connect(self):
    print('connect (got here!)')
    self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
    self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
    print('self.room_name: ' + str(self.room_name))

    valid_connection = await database_sync_to_async(self.verify_chat_room_key)()
    print('valid_connection: ' + str(valid_connection))

    # Join room group
    # async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
    #     self.room_group_name,
    #     self.channel_name
    # )
    await self.accept()

def verify_chat_room_key(self):
    print('~~~in verify method...~~~')
    return True
```

**Edit: Below is the stacktrace showing the python debugs:**

```
HTTP GET /confirmed-trade/334/ 200 [1.28, 127.0.0.1:53877]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat/334/ [127.0.0.1:58882]
HTTP GET /static/favicon.png 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:53877]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat/334/ [127.0.0.1:59246]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/334/ [127.0.0.1:59246]
disconnect
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/chat/334/ [127.0.0.1:65175]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/334/ [127.0.0.1:58882]
disconnect
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/334/ [127.0.0.1:65175]
disconnect
```

Comment: you're calling `database_sync_to_async` twice - once in `connect`, wrapping `verify_chat_room_key` there, the second time in `verify_chat_room_key`. Why? I think that's not correct and you should call it only once.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Thanks for pointing that out. I removed the duplicate `database_sync_to_async` (code has been updated). I'm still getting the same error though

Comment: is there any traceback in the terminal where Django is running?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I added the debug logs from django. I added a debug at the start of the `connect` method and I don't even see that in the django logs, so it looks like I may not have my methods set up correctly, even though I copied my code from the `django-channels` documentaiton: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/databases.html

Comment: Sorry but the code is a total mess. Is the class inherited from `AsyncWebsocketConsumer` class or `WebsocketConsumer` or something else? You're mixing there both approaches together so it cant work but it's not obvious which one should that be. My suggestion is to delete everything and start from scratch following the official docs, eg: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_3.html

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Thanks for your help! You were right, i was inheriting from `WebsocketConsumer` instead of `AsyncWebsocketConsumer`. I ended up keeping everything as synchronous so the problem is solved. Are you good with the security side of using channels? I'm trying to make my live chat more secure, would you be interested in reviewing my code? I will pay you and send you an etransfer beforehand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237263/discussion-between-tom-and-yedpodtrzitko).

Answer (score 0):

`self.accept()` is asynchronous, so it should be:

```
await self.accept()
```

Comment: I made this update but I'm still seeing the same error. It wouldn't have anything to do with the fact i'm running on localhost would it? I updated my question with a few more debugs. I'm still not seeing any of the debugs, so it's not even reaching the `connect` method still

Answer (score 0):

> from channels.db import database_sync_to_async

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    """ handshake websocket front end """

    room_name = None
    room_group_name = None

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        """Creating a new variable """

        self.botname = await database_sync_to_async(self.get_name)()

        print(self.botname)
   

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    """ Creating a Function """
    def get_name(self):
        return CustomUser.objects.filter(groups__id = self.room_name).filter(is_bot = True)[0].username
```

may be, helpful for you